# .html в конце URL кастомной записи "ломает" ссылки на другие записи того же типа

Tags: wordpress

**Дано:**

Есть сайт с товарами. Для товаров создан *custom post type* *catalog*. У товаров есть характеристики и связи между собой в виде произвольных полей, которые созданы с помощью плагина *Advanced custom fields*.

Для отображения товаров я создал шаблон `single-catalog.php`. На странице с товаром отображаются ссылки на связанные товары. Ссылки берутся с помощью `get_permalink();` Код шаблона:

```
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <hr>
                        <div itemprop="description">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Характеристики</h2>
                                    <?php 
                                    $fields = get_field_objects(); ?>
                            <div class="characteristics">
                                <div class="characteristics__table">
                                        <?php 
                                            foreach ($fields as $field) { ?>
                                                <?php if ($field['value'] != ''  
                                                            && $field['label'] != 'Похожие товары'  
                                                            && $field['label'] != 'Маленькая картинка'  
                                                            && $field['label'] != 'Цена')  { ?>
                                                <dl class="characteristics__tr">
                                                    <dt class="characteristics__th"><?php echo $field['label']; ?></dt>
                                                    <dd class="characteristics__td"><?php echo $field['value']; ?></dd>
                                                </dl>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                    <figure class="characteristics__image" itemprop="image">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <?php $get_description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
                                if(!empty($get_description)){
                                 ?>
                                 <figcaption>
                                    <?php echo $get_description; ?>
                                 </figcaption>
                                 <?php } ?>
                                    </figure>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div><!-- end of .characteristics -->
                                <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                                    <strong>Цена: </strong>
                                    <?php if (get_field('цена')) : ?>
                                        <span itemprop="price">
                                            <?php the_field('цена'); ?>
                                        </span>
                                        <span itemprop="priceCurrency">RUB</span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                              <!-- Препараты в составе -->
                              <?php $animals = get_field('похожие_товары'); ?>
                              <?php if ($animals) : ?>
                                <div>
                                        <h2>Похожие на <?php the_title(); ?> товары</h2>
                                    <?php foreach ($animals as $animal): ?>
                                        <?php $animal_id = $animal->ID; ?>
                                        <div class="price-box">
                                            <a class="aligncenter" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($animal_id)); ?>"><?php echo $animal->post_title; ?></a>
                                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($animal_id)); ?>">
                                                <img class="aligncenter" width="70" height="70" src="<?php echo get_field('маленькая_картинка', $animal_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $animal->post_title; ?>">
                                            </a>
                                        Цена: от <?php echo get_field('цена', $animal_id); ?> рублей
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                    <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis blanditiis maiores quibusdam, nostrum inventore labore odio quasi possimus incidunt ducimus aut molestias earum velit adipisci iure numquam modi explicabo mollitia!
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>
                              <?php endif; ?>


                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'iconic-one' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                    <footer class="entry-meta">
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'iconic-one' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
                </article><!-- #post -->
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Проблема:**

Клиенту нужно, чтобы на конце url товаров было расширение .html. Для этого я взял следующий код [отсюда](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59024/add-html-dot-html-extension-to-custom-post-types), добавил его в `functions.php` и обновил постоянные ссылки.

```
  add_action( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules' );
  function rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
      $new_rules = array();
      foreach ( get_post_types() as $t )
          $new_rules[ $t . '/([^/]+)\.html$' ] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $t . '&name=$matches[1]';
      return $new_rules + $rules;
  }

  add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink' ); // for cpt post_type_link (rather than post_link)
  function custom_post_permalink ( $post_link ) {
      global $post;
      $type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
      return home_url( $type . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html' );
  }

  add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', '__return_false' );
```

Расширение .html добавилось, однако на странице с товаром все ссылки на записи связанных товаров ведут на текущий товар, а не на соответствующие страницы. Если убрать добавление .html, все работает как надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю что с этим кодом. Мне помог решить проблему плагин [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

В настройках Постоянных ссылок плагин добавляет поле для пермалинков кастомных записей. В этом поле я прописал `/%postname%.html`

.html в конце url добавляется, а `get_permalink` возвращает правильные ссылки. Всем спасибо. Все свободны)